# Cassandra Streaming error - Unknown keyspace system_traces

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In our dev cluster, which has been running smooth before, when we replace a node (which we have been doing constantly) the following failure occurs and prevents the replacement node from joining.

cassandra version is 2.0.7

What can be done about it?

```
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.128.---.---] 2014-11-19 12:35:58,007 StreamSession.java (line 420) [Stream #9cad81f0-6fe8-11e4-b575-4b49634010a9] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown keyspace system_traces
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:260)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.addTransferRanges(StreamSession.java:239)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.prepare(StreamSession.java:436)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:368)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There is an issue opened: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9628

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was trying to setup my cluster, and as I was experimenting with different switches in cassandra.yaml, I restarted the service multiple times and removed the system dir under data directory (/var/lib/cassandra/data as mentioned [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html)).

I guess for some reason cassandra tries to load system_traces keyspace and fails (the other dir under /var/lib/cassandra/data), and nodetool throws this error. You can just remove both system and system_traces before starting cassandra service, or even better delete all content of bommitlog, data and savedcache there.

This works obviously if you dont have any data just yet in the system.

Comment: Deleting those directories will not help in my case, as it is a fresh machine with absolutely no data.